# Does xcode require images of exact resolution for background images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

While setting background image for ios, does each resolution need to have images of its corresponding resolution? Do I need to have images of different resolutions saved in the root file or can I just add one image with resolution for iphone 6+ and let it resize with auto layout?
I use `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work if you have patterns in the image, you need to have three sizes `1x`, `2x` and `3x`.

But if you use a `UIImageView` which is full screen size, then you can use only one large scale image `3x`.

The below code just repeat the pattern if the image is small, and if the image is large it will show the some portion of that image.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
```

Comment: Could you explain the use of UIImageView in this context?

Comment: You're using `self.view.backgroundColor` right now, what you can do is to place a full screen size `UIImageView` on the view and place your image on it.

Comment: Alright, got it..I have 5 buttons in the app. If i set a size for them, say 75x75, will it change automatically according to screen resolution if I checked Equal Height, Equal Width and Aspect Ratio in the in Auto-layout?

Comment: that depends on your constraints, right now you have not fixed the `w` and `h` so it will change. And why don't you give it a shot and come to a conclusion.